# Correct place for accessing repositories in MVVM

Tags: mvvm, architecture, command

My UWP project follows the MVVM pattern (or it least is supposed to) and I'm currently refactoring it as it suffers from the "god viewmodel" problem: the page viewmodels do basically everything and this is really hard to maintain.

Currently a typical page viewmodel does these things:

- It handles initialization when a page is navigated to: It fetches the models from the repositories and creates viewmodels that "wrap around" the models of my business layer and exposes them to the view with properties.
- It exposes `ICommand` properties that are implemented with `DelegateCommand`, which call methods on my page viewmodel. These methods change some stuff in the sub-viewmodels and persist the changes by calling the repositories.
- It listens to events that are published on an `EventAggregator`. It might receive events like `ModelChangedEvent` or `ModelAddedEvent`, which are created by the persistence layer when a model was changed by a third party. If the page view model receives an event like this, the view model updates the correct sub-view model.

So I have this architecture:

```
+-------------------------+
| Page                    |
+-------------------------+
    |  binds to properties                      
    |  calls commands
   \|/                      subscribes to changes from external
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| PageViewModel           | -----------------------               |
+-------------------------+                       |               |
    |   creates                                   |               |
   \|/  updates                   gets models     |               |
+-------------------------+       stores models   |               |
| ContentViewModel        |                       |               |
+-------------------------+                       |               |
    |   wraps around                              |               |
   \|/                                           \|/              |
+-------------------------+   loads     +----------------------+  |
| ContentModel            | <---------  | IContentRepository   |  |
+-------------------------+   stores    +----------------------+  |
                                                  | notifies of   |
                                                  | changes       |
                                                 \|/              |
                                        +----------------------+  |
                                        | IEventAggregator     |<-+
                                        +----------------------+
```

I want to refactor the "god-like" `PageViewModel`s by putting the `Commands` into their own file and by changing how updates received from the `EventAggregator` are handled. But I have a few questions about this:

Let's imagine there is an `AddContentCommand` that is supposed to create a new `ContentModel` entity and immediately stores it in the database. Should `AddContentCommand` be injected with `IContentRepository` and persist the new object by calling the repository? Or should this be done on `PageViewModel`? How should the `PageViewModel` be notified of the addition? Should this be done directly by calling some method on `PageViewModel` from `AddContentCommand` or should this be done through the EventAggregator? Should `AddContentCommand` even have a reference to `PageViewModel` at all?

Would there be issues if each ContentViewModel subscribed to changes on IEventAggregator and updated itself accordingly? Or is it better if PageViewModel subscribes to it and tells the dependent view models to update, as it is done right now?

Comment: Try to add an Interactors/Use Cases layer, this layer is called from ViewModels/Presenters and uses repositories (the repositories are injected to them). The ViewModel should use those interactors/use cases, and you could divide a lot of logic to many interactors (PageFileInteractor, PageAddContentInteractor, ...).

Comment: Rather than moving the commands them selves to other files, maybe rather look into refactoring all the possible "domain logic" or what ever logic to separate services. Or look into CQRS to have clear seperate commands / queries which would encapsulate the logic into the commands or queries. Regarding the add example, I believe that the pageviewmodel should be listening for domain events, and do what ever it needs to do when a content was succesfully added. And subscribing to events in multiple places is not a problem. Just remember to unsubscribe when you dispose / don't need to listen.

Comment: And try to keep the events anti generic :). So for example, try to not use events like "ItemAdded", but rather a event like "ContentPageAddFinished"

Comment: Thanks @tjugg, I'll look into CQRS! I didn't know about this. What advantage would there be with having separate services (or interactors from @user9335240) over having Commands with knowledge of the repositories? About the non-generic events... I'm afraid I already have those in my code. Turned out to be a bit of a problem as I now want to publish these events according to data from Entity Framework's ChangeTracker, which isn't generic... Had to write some crazy reflection code for this.

Comment: In CRQS the command handler knows about repositories and the command is just the contract. Read about it a bit, it is somewhat similar what you are thinking of doing with your ICommands.